# Scala and Java data structures

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion

I'm new to Scala and have imported an external Java (nmap4J) library that returns an object called:

```
class org.nmap4j.data.nmaprun.Verbose
```

- How do I determine what the object type is in scala?
- How would I then convert it to something thats usable in Scala?

I'm assuming I would ned to use the Scala Java Conversions, but I'm a little confused as where to start.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions

Answer (score 3):

You can use it just like you'd use it in Java, and it's type doesn't change: it's `org.nmap4j.data.nmaprun.Verbose`.

Conversions and Converters are intended to transform a Java standard library collection into a Scala standard library collection and vice versa. Generally speaking, if you have a Java collection that is not from the standard library, there's likely some reason for it to be different, and converting it to Scala would defy its purpose.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try again. When I tried to iterate over the object I was getting type mismatch errors which seemed to imply there there was a mismatch. Is there any easy way to dump the object to string?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm missing something here. I still can't determine how I can iterate over this object and get/use its contents.

Comment: @user1513388 from [what I can see Verbose](https://github.com/narkisr/nmap4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nmap4j/data/nmaprun/Verbose.java) is not intended to be iterated in neither java or scala. You only can call .getLevel/.setLevel methods and access to public constants, not much specific for scala.

Comment: Sorry - maybe I'm being stupid here. I just need to get the contents of Verbose! But seem to be struggling to get to it!

Answer (score 0):

### type conversion

Lets say you have an unknown `Object` (scala `Any` / `AnyRef`) and you think it is a class of Verbose:

```
import org.nmap4j.data.nmaprun.Verbose

def checkObj(in: Any) {
  in match {
    case v: Verbose =>
      // do something with v

    case _ =>
      // do error handling
}
```

This is the scala way of doing `isInstanceOf` / `asInstanceOf`. Almost always you can treat a java class like a scala class.

### list conversion

If your framework gives you java collections, you import, as you said correctly, java conversions.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

def doSomething(list: java.util.List[Any]) {
  // map is now possible due to the implicit conversion of list
  list.map(el => doStuff(el))

  // other methods
  list.toSeq
  list.foreach(println)
}
```